# JPA Commit issues with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am having issues with Oracle database. I am trying to update an entity and pass the updated entity to another method in the same transaction. This works using `mysql` database but doesn't work in `Oracle` database.

**Entity Class**

```
public class EntityA
{
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer versionNo;
    //getters and setters
}

@Transactional //From Spring
public class EntityService
{
    @Inject
    @Named("myService")
    private MyService service;

    public void modify(final EntityA data)
    {
        EntityA entity = persistenceManager.merge(data);
        service.serializeEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that, before `persistenceManager.merge(data);` is called, the `versionNo` field is still zero. After the call to `persistenceManager.merge(data);`, the value of `versionNo` field in the returned object i.e. `entity` is still zero. This object is then passed to `service.serializeEntity(entity);` which serialized the object with `versionNo` zero. But after the method i.e. `update` returns, the `versionNo` in the database changes to `1`. Is there a way of getting the uncommitted modified `EntityA` before passing it to `service.serializeEntity(entity);` because i need to serialize the modified object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling

```
persistenceManager.flush();
```

after the `merge()` call.

That will force the update to the database even though the transaction hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: I know that works, is there no other way of achieving that. `Mysql` seems to do that by default.

Comment: There's no guarantee _any_ data will be flushed before the transaction commits so if your code relies on it flush() is the way to go...